# Eclipse plugin for TestNG coverage

Tags: eclipse-plugin, code-coverage, testng

Does anybody know about an Eclipse plug-in to analyze code coverage for TestNG unit tests?

Answer (score 10):

[EclEmma](http://www.eclemma.org/) can be run on TestNG test suites.  You can also run a group of test or a given TestNG class with it.  It requires the [TestNg plug-in](http://testng.org/doc/eclipse.html)

On EclEmma plugin, choose "coverage configuration..." and select the TestNG tab.

Answer (score 1):

Yes [EclEmma](http://www.eclemma.org/) is the best one. You can also try maven based [cobertura](http://blogs.codehaus.org/people/brett/archives/001334_test_ng_and_cobertura_in_maven_2.html) which is also good enough.

Answer (score 1):

I also use EclEmma , ever had a look at [Clover](http://www.atlassian.com/software/clover/) ? - very , very nice , but not open source.